# How to create and link an overview query of total usage per customer?

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

We've got several tables that look like this:

```
UID | ReportDate | Customernumber | XenAppUsers | Users

D3A | 2014-02-24 15:45:0.017 | 10028 | 7 | the names of the users

B5B | 2014-02-01 15:17:0.156 | 10028 | 10 | the names of the users
```

I've created a view to select the Maximum number of Users per month:

```
SELECT        Debiteurennummer, MAX(XenAppUsers) AS XAUsers, MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
FROM            dbo.XenAppUsers
GROUP BY Debiteurennummer, MONTH(ReportDatum)
```

This will give me:

```
Debiteurennummer | XAUsers | Maand

10026 | 14 | 2

10028 | 8 | 2

10039 | 38 | 2
```

Another View:

```
SELECT        Debiteurennummer, MAX(Mailboxcount) AS MailBoxCount, MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
FROM            dbo.Mailboxcount
GROUP BY Debiteurennummer, MONTH(ReportDatum)
```

will give me:

```
Debiteurennummer | MailBoxCount | Maand

10001 | 72 | 2

10026 | 28 | 2

10028 | 9 | 2

10039 | 64 | 2

10050 | 10 | 2
```

Further we have a `Customer` table which contains:

```
Debiteurennummer | Relatie
```

Now I would like to create a View that shows the max numbers of products used per month and per customer looking like this:

```
Relatie | Number | XenAppUsers | Mailboxusers | product3 | product4 | product5 | etc.

Customer1 | 10001 | 10 | 10 | "NULL" | 5 | "NULL" | "NULL"

Customer2 | 10002 | "Null" | 15 | "NULL" | "NULL" | 15 | 80
```

Can anyone help me on the T-SQL code to create this View in `Microsoft SQL 2012`?

Comment: if the number of products is not too large, then the easiest way to get the results you need is joining each view by customer/month.

Comment: Hi Jayvee thanks for the reply. Can you provice a sample of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something on these lines:

```
DECLARE @month INT -- month to report
SET @month = 2
SELECT  c.relatie ,
        c.Debiteurennummer ,
        @month ,
        view1.XAUsers ,
        view2.Mailboxcount , ...
FROM    CUSTOMER c
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Debiteurennummer ,
                            MAX(XenAppUsers) AS XAUsers ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
                    FROM    dbo.XenAppUsers
                    GROUP BY Debiteurennummer ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum)
                  ) VIEW1 ON c.customer = view1.Debiteurennummer
                             AND view1.maand = @month
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Debiteurennummer ,
                            MAX(Mailboxcount) AS MailBoxCount ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
                    FROM    dbo.Mailboxcount
                    GROUP BY Debiteurennummer ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum)
                  ) VIEW2 ON c.customer = view2.Debiteurennummer
                             AND view2.maand = @month
        LEFT JOIN ... view3, view4, view5 ...
```

Comment: Hi @Jayvee, thanks again for the reply. We've tried this and it gets closer but we're not there yet. Now we get ea 4 lines per customer:<br />  `Debiteurennummer Relatie EEAMaand EEA EESMaand EES EFSMaand EFS EMSMaand EMS MBMaand MailBoxCount XAMaand XAUsers
10001 Customer1   1 2 1 80   2 72  
10001 Customer1   1 2 2 35   2 72  
10001 Customer1   2 54 1 80   2 72  
10001 Customer1   2 54 2 35   2 72  
`

Comment: Hi @Jayee, What we would like to achieve is the following layout: <br />
`Customer , number, month, product1, product2, product3, etc.
 Customer1, 10001, 01, 0, 2, 80, etc.
 Customer1, 10001, 02, 0, 54, 35, etc.
 Customer2, 10002, 01, 10, 0, 0, etc.
 Customer2, 10002, 02, 11, 0, 0, etc.`

Any idea how to group it by month and don't show 2 rows per month per customer?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is a more generic solution, it creates a Cartesian with customers and months and then simply left join it to the views:

```
SELECT  c.relatie ,
        c.Debiteurennummer ,
        c.maand ,
        view1.XAUsers ,
        view2.Mailboxcount , ...
FROM    
(SELECT relatie, Debiteurennummer FROM CUSTOMER 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) x(maand)) y ON 1=1) c
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Debiteurennummer ,
                            MAX(XenAppUsers) AS XAUsers ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
                    FROM    dbo.XenAppUsers
                    GROUP BY Debiteurennummer ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum)
                  ) VIEW1 ON c.customer = view1.Debiteurennummer
                             AND view1.maand = c.maand
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Debiteurennummer ,
                            MAX(Mailboxcount) AS MailBoxCount ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum) AS Maand
                    FROM    dbo.Mailboxcount
                    GROUP BY Debiteurennummer ,
                            MONTH(ReportDatum)
                  ) VIEW2 ON c.customer = view2.Debiteurennummer
                             AND view2.maand = c.maand
        LEFT JOIN ... view3, view4, view5 ...
```